# How do I access all elements of a list without writing each index? (Vowel remover program in PYTHON)

Tags: python

My program basically allows users to input a word of their choice and after that, give them the option to remove certain vowels of their choice.

It goes like this:

```
v = ['A', 'E','I','O','U','AE', 'EA', 'AI', 'IA', 'AO','OA', 'AU','UA',
     'EI','IE','EO','OE','EU','UE','IO','OI', 'IU','UI', 'OU','UO',
     'AEI','AEU', 'EIO','EIU','IOU', 'AEIO','AEIU','EIOU',
     'AEIOU'
]

keepOrDeleteVowel1 = input("Would you like to delete some vowels?  Type 'yes' to choose which vowels you would like to delete, or 'no' to type a new word.").upper()

if keepOrDeleteVowel1.upper() == "YES":
                            initial_word = input("Please type the word again: ")
                            vowel = input("Type the vowels you want to remove.  Tip: If your word begins or ends with a vowel, try not to delete the vowel because the word might not be recognizable.")
                            if type(vowel) is str:
                                if len(vowel) <=5 and vowel == v[0-24]:
                                    initial_word = initial_word.replace(vowel.lower(), '')
                                    initial_word = initial_word.replace(vowel.upper(), '')
                                else:
                                    print('Wrong input.')
                            print("This is your word: " + initial_word +  "." + " Enjoy your new license plate! Thank you for using this app.")
```

In case you were wondering, the top section is a list of all possible inputs for the user when he chooses which vowels he wants to remove from his word.

If you can catch it, `vowel == v[0-24]:` is my attempt to try and access all the elements in the top list, `v`.  How should I change that?

Basically, if the user types any element in the top list, say, 'IU', he would have the letters I and U removed from his original word.

Basically, the logic of that if statement:

```
if len(vowel) <=5 and vowel == v[0-24]:
```

is if the length of the user's response is less than or equal to 5 and the user's input matches any element of the list `v` .... remove the vowels...you get the point.

I know that if statement is wrong, so what should I change it to?

Comment: There are a lot more possible valid entries: there are 5 + 5*4 + 5*4*3 + 5*4*3*2 + 5*4*3*2*1 = 325, including only the ones with 1 to 5 vowels, without repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `vowel == v[0-24]` with `vowel.upper() in v`.

Comment: This won't be enough, though: if you enter 'AEI', the rest of the code will try to replace the whole 'AEI' string from the original word, not each individual letter. Furthermore, lots of possible, valid entries are missing from the list, as 'IOA'. Using a `set` is the way to go in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test if a set of letters is included in another set of letters. So, the perfect thing to use is a `set`, see [the documentation in Python built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

We create a set of the allowed vowels from a string. It will be the set `{'U', 'O', 'I', 'A', 'E'}` (sets are not ordered).

Later, we will create a set of the vowels you enter (converted to uppercase), and check if this set is included in (or equal to) the first one, with the `<=` operator:

```
>>> set('AUE') <= set('AEIOU')
True
>>> set('ARIO')<= set('AEIOU')
False
```

Then, we'll iterate on the vowels we entered, and replace each one (uppercase and lowercase) in our initial word.

```
all_vowels = set('AEIOU')
# {'U', 'O', 'I', 'A', 'E'}
keepOrDeleteVowel1 = input("Would you like to delete some vowels?"
                           " Type 'yes' to choose which vowels you would like to delete,"
                           " or 'no' to type a new word.").upper()

if keepOrDeleteVowel1.upper() == "YES":
    initial_word = input("Please type the word again: ")
    vowels = input("Type the vowels you want to remove."
                   " Tip: If your word begins or ends with a vowel,"
                   " try not to delete the vowel because the word"
                   " might not be recognizable.").upper()
    if set(vowels) <= all_vowels:
        for vowel in vowels:
            initial_word = initial_word.replace(vowel.lower(), '')
            initial_word = initial_word.replace(vowel.upper(), '')
        print(initial_word)
    else:
         print('Wrong input.')
```

As a sidenote: as the strings in your code were very long, I cut them using Python's automatic concatenation: strings following each other are simply concatenated.